# How to get customer group in custom module admin page forms in magento 2?

Tags: magento2.2, custom, customer-group

I am creating a custom module.
I want to assign **Customer Group**/s to one of my custom table.

In my **Grid.php** I did customization like this

**Path : `app\code\Myconpany\BusinessPartner\Block\Adminhtml\Businesspartner`**

In **protected function _prepareColumns()**

```
$this->addColumn(
        'customer_group',
        [
            'header' => __('Customer Group'),
            'index' => 'customer_group',
            'type' => 'options',
            'options' => $this->getOptionArray2()
        ]
    );
```

In **getOptionArray2() function**

```
public function getOptionArray2()
{
    $customerGroups = $this->_customerGroup->toOptionArray();
    
    $data_arrays=array(); 

    foreach($customerGroups as $cg){
     
      $data_arrays[$cg['value']]=$cg['label'];

    }

    return($data_arrays);
}
```

Above all my **customer group**/s are retrieve

In **main.php file**

```
$fieldset->addField(
        'customer_group',
        'select',
        [
            'label' => __('Customer Group'),
            'title' => __('Customer Group'),
            'name' => 'customer_group',
            
            'options' => $this->getOptionArray2(),
            'disabled' => $isElementDisabled
        ]
    );
```

But my **customer group**/s are not loading in the form.
[image]

1 . What I missed here?

2 . Is there any way to get **customer group**?

Comment: What is `$this->_customerGroup`'s type?

Comment: that i am getting from this \Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Group\Collection $customerGroup,

Comment: Is there any reason you're not passing that directly to options in your fieldset initialization? I would assume you don't need to modify anything and that ->toOptionArray() would be what you pass to a fieldset directly.

Comment: previously getOptionArray2 is a static function.in static function i cannot use $this.

Comment: Have you defined getOptionArray2() in your main.php file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thank you for attempting me to help in this.

Here what i missed is not correctly trying to access my **getOptionArray2()** function in **main.php** from **grid.php**.
I fixed this with some changes in my code.
I will explain in detail so future users can use this approach.

In **Grid.php** i want to get the customer groups.i will mention the essential steps to achieve this.Rest of the codes are same.

```
<?php
namespace Myconpany\BusinessPartner\Block\Adminhtml\Businesspartner;

class Grid extends \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Extended
{
//Other protected variables
/**
 * Customer Group
 *
 * @var \Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Group\Collection
 */
protected $_customerGroup;

public function __construct(
//--**--//
\Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Group\Collection $customerGroup,
    array $data = []
) {
    $this->_customerGroup = $customerGroup; 
    parent::__construct($context, $backendHelper, $data);
}

//In _**prepareColumns** function
protected function _prepareColumns()
{
    /* codes going here */

    $this->addColumn(
        'customer_group',
        [
            'header' => __('Customer Group'),
            'index' => 'customer_group',
            'type' => 'options',
            'options' => $this->getOptionArray2()
        ]
    );
/* codes going here */
}
```

**function getOptionArray2() : In Grid.php**

```
public function getOptionArray2()
{

    $customerGroups = $this->_customerGroup->toOptionArray();

    $data_arrays=array(); 

    foreach($customerGroups as $cg){
      $data_arrays[$cg['value']]=$cg['label'];
    }
    return($data_arrays);        
}
```

Normally if we creating using any module creators, this function should be a `static` function.But i wrote it as `public` function.

My function is **getValueArray2() : In Grid.php**

```
public function getValueArray2()
{
    $data_array=array();
    foreach($this->getOptionArray2() as $k=>$v){
       $data_array[]=array('value'=>$k,'label'=>$v);        
    }
    return($data_array);
}
```

Normally if we creating using any module creators, this function should be a `static` function.But i wrote it as `public` function.

In **Main.php** where the form is populating we want to do some customization like this.Want to create an instance of my grid.php and access the function through this instance.

```
<?php
namespace Myconpany\BusinessPartner\Block\Adminhtml\Businesspartner\Edit\Tab;
/**
* Businesspartner edit form main tab
*/
class Main extends \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Form\Generic implements \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Tab\TabInterface
{ 
protected $_grid; 
public function __construct(\Eight25media\BusinessPartner\Block\Adminhtml\Businesspartner\Grid $grid,
    array $data = []
) {
    $this->_grid = $grid;
    parent::__construct($context, $registry, $formFactory, $data);
}
```

My **_prepareForm** function like this

```
protected function _prepareForm()
{ 
    /* codes going here */

    $fieldset->addField(
        'customer_group',
        'select',
        [
            'label' => __('Customer Group'),
            'title' => __('Customer Group'),
            'name' => 'customer_group',

            'options' => $this->_grid->getOptionArray2(),
            'disabled' => $isElementDisabled
        ]
    );  
/* codes going here */
return parent::_prepareForm();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I simply did the following in my form.

```
public function __construct(
    ....
    \Magento\Customer\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Group\Options $groups,
    array $data = []
) {
    ....
    $this->groups = $groups;
    parent::__construct($context, $registry, $formFactory, $data);
}

....

$fieldset->addField(
    'customer_group_id',
    'select',
    [
        'label'    => __('Group'),
        'name'     => 'customer_group_id',
        'required' => true,
        'values'   => $this->groups->toOptionArray(),
    ]
);
```

Hope this helps!